# MySQL delete data without query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a client that is describing an occurrence when they are adding new data from a web form.  If the submitted data matches any existing database entries, the system deletes the existing entry.

I've checked the scripts and I don't see a DELETE query that would affect the related table.  There are UPDATE queries, none of which affect a field in the DB indicating a deletion or marked as deleted.

Are there ways data could be lost without the execution of a DELETE query?

As asked for, here's the "create table" statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `msp_zip_codes` 
(
     `zip_code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
     `city` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
     `state_prefix` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `county` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `area_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityType` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityAliasAbbreviation` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityAliasName` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
     `lat` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `lon` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `time_zone` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Elevation` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CountyFIPS` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
     `DayLightSaving` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PreferredLastLineKey` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
     `ClassificationCode` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `MultiCounty` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `StateFIPS` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityStateKey` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityAliasCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PrimaryRecord` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityMixedCase` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CityAliasMixedCase` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     KEY `AreaCode` (`area_code`),
     KEY `CityAliasCode` (`CityAliasCode`),
     KEY `CityStateKey` (`CityStateKey`),
     KEY `ClassificationCode` (`ClassificationCode`),
     KEY `PreferredLastLineKey` (`PreferredLastLineKey`),
     KEY `ZipCode` (`zip_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What programming language or framework(s) are you using?

Comment: If you could post the queries, we could check.  Alternatively, there might be a trigger on your tables(s).

Comment: cakePHP - There are many queries, I could post them selectively, though.

Comment: Please post the table create statement. There's a good chance it's a unique constraint.

Comment: It seems there are no events or triggers

Comment: enable the binary log or general log.  It will record all statements executed by the server.  Look for your deletes there.

Comment: Why you don't have any primary key? If there is no primary/unique index what do You mean by "If the submitted data matches any existing database entries"?

Comment: If I had made it, there would be a primary.  I don't know who made this DB. What I mean is, if there are repeating ZIP codes.

Comment: Can You post these UPDATE queries? Maybe data is not deleted but overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is that the table has an `UPDATE TRIGGER` set which fires every time there's an update. Or the other one, there's an `Event Scheduler` running on the server.

Code to show all triggers on the database:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS a
WHERE  a.TRIGGER_SCHEMA LIKE CONCAT('%', 'databaseNameHERE', '%')
```

Code to show all events on the database:

```
SHOW EVENTS FROM databaseNameHERE;
```

Comment: Thanks for those two queries.  Results are blank for each.

Comment: @ypercube I used the correct DB name in the queries, but thanks for checking.

Comment: This did it, had to look on their real live server rather than the dev server.